# Does Cross-Validation Really Work?

Tags: self-study, cross-validation

This question was taken from "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Friedman, Hastie and Tibshirani (question 7.10)

Consider a scenario with N = 20 samples in two equal-sized classes, and p = 500 quantitative predictors that are independent of the class labels. The true error rate of any classifier is 50%. Consider a simple univariate classifier: a single split that minimizes the misclassification error (a “stump”). Suppose that all of the p predictors are binary, and hence there is no need to estimate split points. 
Then if p is very large, we can probably find a predictor that splits the entire training data perfectly, and hence would split the validation data (one-fifth of data) perfectly as well. This predictor would therefore have zero cross-validation error. Does this mean that cross-validation does not provide a good estimate of test error in this situation?

My intuition would be that in this case, the result from cross-validation will actually be misleading - the model will score very highly in cross-validation and on a test set, but perform very poorly out-of-sample. Am I correct?

Comment: How *many* trees do you think you will have that split the training fold well?  Will all of them preform well on the hold out fold?

Comment: Why do you think it that splitting the training data perfectly implies that the same predictor will split the validation data perfectly as well?

Comment: @jbowman, isn't that the assumption we are making in the problem? That by chance, we got a predictor that replicates the target variable in our samples exactly. Looks to me like that predictor will be selected by the decision stump, and it will classify the validation data perfectly; the same will happen across all folds. No?

Comment: @MatthewDrury, not sure what you mean. Looks like here, we are using just one decision tree of depth 1? I don't see how this scenario is different from actually using the real target values in the set of features - in which case we would expect both cross-validation, in-sample and out-of-sample errors of our model to be 0. The only difference here that I can see is that our predictor will not work out-of-sample.

Comment: Ah, on more careful rereading I see I didn't quite understand your hypothetical.

Comment: @rinspy I follow.  So we probably have one feature that splits the training and hold-out data perfectly.  May there be other features that split the training data perfectly but do *not* split the validation perfectly?  If so, which one would get chosen as the correct feature to split upon based on *only* the in-fold training data?

Comment: @MatthewDrury thank you, that makes sense now. The intuition is that if the features are correlated with the target by chance alone, there will be many more such features in the training set of each fold that do not correlate with the corresponding validation set. If the feature was a true predictor, this would be less likely, and we would get a higher cross-validation score. You should submit your comment as an answer!

Comment: It seems to me that the point the book is trying to make is that validation only works as long as you don't do too many comparisons on the validation data. In your scenario, 500 models are compared on 4 samples of validation data, so just by chance each model has a probability of $(\frac{1}{2})^{4}=\frac{1}{16}$ of getting it exactly right, and thus the probability that at least one model gets it exactly right is $1-(1-\frac{1}{16})^{500}\approx1$. The validation error only predicts the out-of-sample error well if this probability is near 0.